# List all files with dates recursively with PHP

Tags: php, date, recursion

Before someone marks this duplicate, please understand that I searched this site, Google searches, and PHP.net.

What I want is super simple. I want a list of all files on a website with a datestamp (last modified). I have found several scripts that claim to do this, but none of them are working.

The best one I have found so far is this one:

```
header("Pragma: public");
  header("Cache-Control: private");
  header("Content-Type: text/csv");
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=age-of-files.csv");

  $result = array();
  $handle =  opendir(".");
     while ($datei = readdir($handle))
     {
          if (($datei != '.') && ($datei != '..'))
          {
               $file = "./".$datei;
               if (!is_dir($file))
                    $result[] = $file;
          }
     }
     closedir($handle);
  foreach($result as $r)
    if (file_exists($r))
      echo substr($r,2).",".date ("m-d-Y", filemtime($r))."\r\n";
```

This works great for the dircetory the script is run in, but it is not recursive. I need it to keep going for every sub directory. My goal is to have a sortable list so I can find files that were modified on or around certain dates.

I am new to PHP, so bear with me. I did some research at PHP.net (I keep seeing people refer to SPL and I'm not sure what that stands for or what it is, but perhaps it is a group of standard PHP classes?), and it looks like I need to be using RecursiveDirectoryIterator somehow.

I found this script that looks great on paper, but running it on my site gives a blank white screen.

```
try
{
        /*** freds home directory ***/
        $rdi = new recursiveDirectoryIterator('/',  FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS | FilesystemIterator::UNIX_PATHS);
        $it = new recursiveIteratorIterator( $rdi );
        while( $it->valid())
        {
                if( !$it->isDir() )
                {
                        echo $it->current().' '.date('Y m d H:i:s', $it->getATime() )."\n";
                }

                /*** move to the next element ***/
                $it->next();
        }
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        /*** echo the error message ***/
        echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I would prefer to use the first script as I like that it creates a csv file (easy to sort), but I am not sure how to reconcile the two. Can someone advise me on how to incorporate RDI into the first script?

Comment: Try it without these `,  FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS | FilesystemIterator::UNIX_PATHS`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little code that I found working very well

```
$rdi = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("path/"); // The directory here
$rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($rdi);

foreach ($rii as $filename=>$cur) {
    echo $cur.' '.date('Y m d H:i:s', $cur->getATime() )."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this, which is similar to the second example that you provided:

```
<?php

$path = __DIR__;

if (!is_dir($path)) {
    throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Path %s does not exist!', $path));
}

if (!is_readable($path)) {
    throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Path %s is not readable!', $path));
}

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path)
);

$files = [];

foreach ($iterator as $fileInfo) {
    if ($fileInfo->isFile()) {
        $files[] = [
            $fileInfo->getFilename(),
            dirname($fileInfo->getPathname()),
            date('c', $fileInfo->getMTime())
        ];
    }
}

print_r($files);
```

Given an example file structure:

[image]

This yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => .DS_Store
            [1] => /private/tmp/rec
            [2] => 2015-08-08T08:28:33+00:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => .DS_Store
            [1] => /private/tmp/rec/0
            [2] => 2015-08-08T08:28:33+00:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.1.txt
            [1] => /private/tmp/rec/0/0.1
            [2] => 2015-08-08T08:27:58+00:00
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0.txt
            [1] => /private/tmp/rec/0
            [2] => 2015-08-08T08:27:58+00:00
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => .DS_Store
            [1] => /private/tmp/rec/1
            [2] => 2015-08-08T08:28:33+00:00
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => .DS_Store
            [1] => /private/tmp/rec/1/1.1
            [2] => 2015-08-08T08:28:27+00:00
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.1.txt
            [1] => /private/tmp/rec/1/1.1
            [2] => 2015-08-08T08:27:58+00:00
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1.txt
            [1] => /private/tmp/rec/1
            [2] => 2015-08-08T08:27:58+00:00
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => rec.php
            [1] => /private/tmp/rec
            [2] => 2015-08-08T08:48:30+00:00
        )

)
```

Each match is stored as a sub-array element containing:

1. Filename
2. Current dirpath
3. Datetime of last modification

It makes some additional checks to ensure that the `$path` provided can be read.

You now have a result set of `$files` in an array, you should be able to reuse some of the code in your first example to output as a .csv file.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll play around with that and see if I can incorporate it into the first example I posted as I think this would be a more eloquent solution.

Comment: No problem. I was rushing out the door yesterday so I didn't have time to complete the answer with .csv export. And.... I'm rushing out now again :) but I'll try to update the answer accordingly when I can, instead of creating an array in the main loop it'd be better to build the .csv directly with `fputcsv()` etc.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is curious, this is what I ended up with. It combines the simplicity and effectiveness of the first answer with the csv of the first example in my question. When I open the csv file in excel, I am able to sort by day easily.

The reason I needed this was to help track down some malware on one of my sites. By having a list of all the files, I can sort by date and look for files that were added on suspicious dates. Or conversely, if I found a known threat on a certain day, I can easily see what other files were modified on that day/time. It helped me immensely in finally ridding my site of the persistent infection. It kept coming back to life because I wasn't able to remove all the files. Using this simple script, I finally found the backdoor shell that had been installed. Phew!

Thanks so much to both answerers! :)

```
<?php
header("Pragma: public");
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Content-Type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=age-of-files.csv");

$rdi = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("."); // The directory here
$rii = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($rdi);

foreach ($rii as $filename=>$cur) {
    echo $cur.', '.date('m-d-Y', $cur->getATime() ).', '.date('H:i:s', $cur->getATime() )."\r\n";
}
?>
```